# Java package does not exist (package org.bouncycastle.cms)

Tags: java, jar

I have install java jar packing by using this command

**java verison (1.8)**

```
CLASSPATH=.:/path/to/bcmail-jdk16-144.jar:/path/to/bcprov-jdk16-144.jar:$CLASSPATH
export CLASSPATH
```

which is required as part of dependency to execute one of java class file

but it is giving below error

```
pkcs7gen.java:8: error: package org.bouncycastle.cms does not exist
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
                           ^
pkcs7gen.java:9: error: package org.bouncycastle.cms does not exist
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
                           ^
pkcs7gen.java:10: error: package org.bouncycastle.cms does not exist
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
                           ^
pkcs7gen.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            CMSSignedDataGenerator sgen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            ^
  symbol:   class CMSSignedDataGenerator
  location: class pkcs7gen
pkcs7gen.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            CMSSignedDataGenerator sgen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
                                              ^
  symbol:   class CMSSignedDataGenerator
  location: class pkcs7gen
pkcs7gen.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
            sgen.addSigner(privateKey, myPubCert,CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable CMSSignedDataGenerator
  location: class pkcs7gen
pkcs7gen.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            CMSSignedData csd = sgen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(dataToSign),true, "BC");
            ^
  symbol:   class CMSSignedData
  location: class pkcs7gen
pkcs7gen.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            CMSSignedData csd = sgen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(dataToSign),true, "BC");
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class CMSProcessableByteArray
  location: class pkcs7gen
Note: pkcs7gen.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors
```

And also how install java jar package using Linux terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear that you have a problem in that the system cannot find the source as directed in the file.  However, one does not normally "install" a jar file.

I would suggest that you first make sure you have the latest java and java runtime engine packages installed.  You need the first to program and the second to run a java program on your computer.

Then you should be able to download the jar file and use it appropriately.

Hope that helps.